# django 2 foreign keys from one model to another model

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to have 2 foreign keys in a model relate to the same model.In the example, I want to have 'date' and 'supervisor' from Timesheet both as foreign keys to DateTimesheet. What I am trying to accomplish is having Timesheet inline with DateTimesheet in the admin and be able to enter date and supervisor once and then enter multiple Timesheets inline without having to enter date or supervisor for every Timesheet.

```
class DateTimesheet(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    supervisor = models.ForeignKey(User)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Daily Timesheet'
        unique_together = (('date', 'supervisor'),)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s | %s' % self.date.strftime("%A, %B %d.")

class Timesheet(models.Model):
    date = models.ForeignKey(DateTimesheet)
    supervisor = models.ForeignKey(DateTimesheet)
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job)
    phase = models.ForeignKey(Phase)
    equip = models.ForeignKey(Equipment, null=True, blank=True)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    local = models.ForeignKey(Local)
    pay_class = models.ForeignKey(PayClass)
    reg = models.IntegerField(max_length=1)
    ot = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, null=True, blank=True)
    bill_rate = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=6, blank=True,null=True)
    bill_hours = models.IntegerField(max_length=2,blank=True,null=True,)
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have to foreign keys on one model pointing to the same model you have to [set `fk_name` on the corresponding inline admin](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-a-model-with-two-or-more-foreign-keys-to-the-same-parent-model):

```
class DateInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = DateTimeSheet
    fk_name = "date"
```

Comment: Okay, that works, but it still doesn't solve my problem of being able to select both date and supervisor and have the rest of the Timesheet model be inline. I can only select either date or supervisor as the foreign key. I guess what I really need is a composite key where the primary key would be date & supervisor.

Comment: Don't you create TWO inlines, one for `date` and one for `supervisor`?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Give them different values for [`related_name`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name).

Comment: When i use the related_name it allows me to syncdb, but it throws an Exception.                                                                 <class 'myproject.timesheet.models.Timesheet'> has more than 1 ForeignKey to <class 'myproject.timesheet.models.DateTimesheet'> when trying to access the admin

Comment: If that's cos you're using an inline in the admin, google the docs for 'fk_name' to find the fix

Answer (score 0):

that's no problem.

You should be getting an error about needing to specify a `related_name` and that information should solve your problem.

You must specify `models.ForeignKey(DateTimeSheet, related_name="something_else")` or else django will complain that the reverse relationship managers need unique names.

To clarify: the `related_name` is what you use in a reverse lookup, like: `datetimesheet.timesheet_set.all()`

When you have two foreign keys to `DateTimesheet`, django needs to be able to differentiate between the two Foreign Keys.